# PostgreSQL MAX and MIN functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I made a database called cars. The table consists of 4 columns: (id, make, model, price).
I want to find the car with the highest price. I ran this code in SQL shell:

```
SELECT id, make, model, price
FROM cars
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM cars);
```

and got the output

```
id  | make  |  model   |  price
946 | Mazda | B-Series | $9937.75
```

I know that there are more expensive cars than this in the data set (ex. $49437.07, $21305.93 . . . ).

I have version 14 of PostgreSQL installed. Can anyone explain what is going wrong here?

Comment: Sample data, table schema and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a great place to start, along with a TAG for your RDBMS!

Comment: My guess is your price is text datatype when it should be numeric. The character "9" is greater than the characters "4" or "2".

Comment: also you should leave the dollar sign out and store the price as a simple decimal value

Comment: Issac, that is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will convert the date type to numeric
`alter table cars alter column price numeric USING (price::numeric);`

then your code would work.

if you have null values in price then you would have to use:

`alter table cars alter column price numeric using nullif(price,'')::numeric;`

Answer (score -1):

No, but I would write

```
select * from cars order by price desc limit 1;
```

Comment: This is non-standard SQL, `top` is not valid syntax for Postgresql

Comment: You are right I updated the query.